# From column of results to rows with same results

Tags: python, row, sequence, flip

I'm really a beginner with python and in classe I'm analyzing a coin toss task. The number of tosses is `1000`, the results possible are `1`,`2`. I'm asked to create row with sequences of same results (such as `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` and then `2 2 2 2 2`,..) and give the length of the longest appearing sequence.

```
from numpy.random import randint, seed
seed(0)

for n in range(1000):
   r = randint(1,3)
   print(r)
```

which gives me a single column reporting the results as follows

```
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
```

I can't manage to find the appropriate code to create those rows of sequences of same results.

Comment: Can you please little more elaborate your problem statement, with proper example of output? This will helps in understanding your problem properly.

Comment: Well, there are two different answers. I think that means noone *really* understand your question. And by the way, I didn't understand your question...

Comment: Yeah... the problem statement is not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the result of each iteration of your for loop.

A simple solution is to create 2 lists, each containing every occurrence of either 1 or 2:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
```

In your for loop, you can use the list.append method to add the value of r to the corresponding list:

```
for n in range(1000):
    r = randint(1, 3)
    if r == 1:
        list1.append(r)
    else:
        list2.append(r)
```

This way, list1 contains every occurrence of the number 1, and list2 contains all the number 2.

You can now print both list, and use len() to get the number of elements in each list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
for n in range(1000):
    r = randint(1, 3)
    if r == 1:
        count1 += 1
    elif r == 2:
        count2 += 1

if count1 > count2:
    print('1'*count1)
    print('2'*count2)
    print('Longest sequence is of 1\'s, with %s occurences'  %count1)
else:
    print('1'*count1)
    print('2'*count2)
    print('Longest sequence is of 2\'s, with %s occurences' %count2)
```